# issue about flask python app deployed in AWS ubuntu server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, flask

I am a new one to flask app. Now I want to deploy a simple app in the AWS ubuntu server following by this blog:https://chrisdtran.com/2017/deploy-flask-on-ec2/.

The code is as following:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
        return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

and config file as following:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        }
}
```

~

After I run:  gunicorn helloworld:app

There are errors that I can't Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8000) as shown in the figure

[image]

Comment: is port 800 open? Also show us your code.

Comment: @MikeTung thanks! what's port 800? you mean security group of EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give gunicorn a specific port:

```
gunicorn helloworld:app -b localhost:8000
```

Comment: thanks! there is still the same issue even after your suggestions.

Comment: thanks, does the error mean that there is another app use the port. Since I have used gunicorn listen another app before:gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -w 4 microblog:app

Comment: You can check whether there is another app on this port: `curl localhost:8000`. If you get the output of your app, gunicorn should work fine. If you get something like "Connection refused", the error is in gunicorn.